# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in Julia

Tags: julia, bloomberg

I have a .jl file that loops for some amount of time with code that looks like this:

```
using Blpapi
using DataFrames

IP = "localhost"
Port = 8194

session = createSession(IP, Port)

tickers = ["ESU7 Index"]

fields = ["BID", "ASK"]

stoptime = DateTime(2017, 9, 5, 15, 31)

df = DataFrame(Ticker = String[], Bid = Float64[], Ask = Float64[], Time = 
   DateTime[])

while(now() < stoptime)

   point = bdp(session, tickers, fields)

   push!(df, [tickers[1], point[tickers[1], "BID"], point[tickers[1], 
      "ASK"], now()])


   sleep(.005)

end

println(df)
```

When I run it, sometimes it crashes and gives an error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. I've noticed that the probability of getting the error increases as "n" decreases.

The bdp() call is to the Bloomberg API for Julia.

Is there something basic I'm doing incorrectly? Or does it go deeper than that?

Comment: No, the error is in `#do something` or a library call therein.  That error means you're trying to access memory you don't have access to — like not handling a null pointer or API error correctly or using `@inbounds` incorrectly.  You're going to need to post more information than that if you want help.  See the [minimal complete verifiable example help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks very much. I updated accordingly.

Comment: Calling a commercial company's API every 5 milliseconds... this probably generates the error. My guess is with `sleep(10.0)` there would be no error (maybe a different data plan can provide this kind of access, but my guess it would cost more).

Comment: Instead of repeatedly calling bdp, you should start a subscription.

Comment: @assylias Is this out there? I know folks have written similar stuff for other languages, but I haven't found it for Julia. So now I'm trying to write it.

Comment: @mattsurw I don't know the Julia API but I suspect it relies on the C or Python API which natively support the subscription mechanism. I can't help much more than that I'm afraid.